Trying to proof two XOR instances
I have proof (truth table) that both instances of XOR are correct. Which means both instances have to be equal to each other.
Yet, I am missing the insight to get from one to the other. My (math) background is rather modest but I would be pleased if someone could help me apply the laws (comm., ass., DeMorgan) to show me.
instance 1: $(\bar a \cdot b)+(a \cdot \bar b)$
instance 2: $(a+b)\cdot \overline{(a \cdot b)}$
I believe I am missing an essential part because I am taking spin-offs that go nowhere...

Since the first instance is already in disjunctive normal form, we can try bringing the second one to the same form.
Note that $\overline{a \cdot b} = \overline{a} + \overline{b}$, hence your second instance is equal to $(a + b) \cdot (\overline{a} + \overline{b})$. This in turn is equal to $a \cdot \overline{a} + a \cdot \overline{b} + b \cdot \overline{a} + b \cdot \overline{b}$. It's easy to see that terms like $a \cdot \overline {a}$ are always false, hence only two disjuncts survive: $a \cdot \overline b + b \cdot \overline a$, which is effectively your first instance up to commutativity of $+$ and $\cdot$.
